# What is the Ukrainian word with the closest meaning to the English verb "waste"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

[Waste](https://www.google.com/#q=waste+definition&*) (*verb*): use or expend carelessly, extravagantly, or to no purpose.

Is there a word in Ukrainian that carries a similar meaning and is derived from a word with an obviously negative connotation? For example the noun of "waste" is "відходи", but can it be converted into a verb in Ukrainian?

I'd like something to use in sentences like:

"Don't waste water!"

"He wasted money on a luxury car."

"The government is wasting a portion of the budget."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- [марнувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/marnuvaty) — Даремно, без користі витрачати гроші, майно тощо. (to spend uselessly, to no purpose — money, assets, etc.)
- [гаяти](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghajaty) — Витрачати марно, марнувати (стосовно часу) (to waste, usually in relation to **time**)

The example sentences above would be:

- *не **марнуй** воду*
- *він **змарнував** гроші на покупку дорогої автівки*
- *уряд **марнує** частину бюджету*

Answer (score 12):

In addition to what [bytebuster said](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/858/4) (actually, his variants are the best, but there are others):

- Ukrainian language has the words [витрачати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vytrachaty) and [тратити](http://sum.in.ua/s/tratyty). They mean literally "to spend", but with additional adverbs: *витрачати [марно](http://sum.in.ua/s/marno)*, *витрачати [дарма](http://sum.in.ua/s/darma) ([даремно](http://sum.in.ua/s/daremno))* ("to spend with no purpose, with no positive effects, needlessly, uselessly, in vain") they mean what you need.

  <sup>BTW, do you notice that *марно* from my answer is a cognate of the *марнувати* (from bytebuster's answer)? I suppose *марнувати* to be a verb created from the adverb *марно*.</sup>
- There is another verb created from *марно* — [марнотратити](http://sum.in.ua/s/marnotratyty). As you can suppose from its look, it's *марно тратити*.
- There is another one created from *тратити* (*витрачати*) — in this case not with adverb or an extra stem, but with prefix *роз-* (which, when added to a verb, often, but not always, increases intensity of the verb) — [розтрачувати (розтрачати, розтратити)](http://sum.in.ua/s/roztrachuvaty) (*розтратити X* — "to spend all of X here and there, to disperse it"). It doesn't always mean careless/needless spends, but most often does (also it can mean a criminal waste of money/resources not owned by the spender, e.g. by a state servant).
- Colloquial, but widely used:

  - [тринькати](http://sum.in.ua/s/trynjkaty) ([розтринькувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/roztrynjkuvaty));
  - [циндрити](http://sum.in.ua/s/cyndryty) ([проциндрювати](http://sum.in.ua/s/PROCYNDRJuVATY)).
  - In figurative sense:

    - [викидати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vykydaty) — "to throw away";
    - [спускати](http://sum.in.ua/s/spuskaty) — "to lower/let down";
    - [мотати](http://sum.in.ua/s/motaty) ([промотувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/promotuvaty)) — "to entwine/coil/etc".
- In specific contexts:

  - [пропивати](http://sum.in.ua/s/propyvaty) — "to spend on drinks";
  - [прогулювати](http://sum.in.ua/s/proghuljuvaty) — "to spend on entertainments";
  - <sub>dial., col., fig.</sub> [вакувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vakuvaty) — "to lose time".
- Rare:

  - <sub>fig.</sub> [розточувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/roztochuvaty) — "to bore/grind/etc (on lathe)";
  - <sub>col.</sub> [збавляти](http://sum.in.ua/s/ZBAVLJaTY) — "to decrease".